# Помогите убрать пробелы

Tags: python, print

Я хочу убрать пробелы при выводе элементов списка.

```
hello  = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in hello:
    print(i)
```

Вывод:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Помогите убрать пробелы между цифрами, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще вариант (andreymal предложил в комментах):

```
print(*hello, end='')
```

Comment: В каких комментах?

Comment: @V.March Уже модераторы удалили за ненадобностью.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда пользуюсь этим вариантом:

```py
hello = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(''.join(hello)) # тут пустая строка '' это разделитель
```

Мой совет Вам: почитайте `PEP-8`, а также про метод `.join`, это все есть в Интернете на русском.